# Get data in field between quotes (i.e. "s)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to select data in quotes in a query? For example, I have a field that contains a value of

```
SYS_Data("THE DATA I WANT")
```

Is there a way to search this in SQL (specifically Oracle)?

I really just need to be able to see if the value in quotes matches (exactly) another field in another table.

Comment: Do you want to *select* (ie "return") only the data in quotes, or *search* for data (ie have a condition in the where clause) in quotes? Your question is unclear, because you use both terms in your question, but they mean very different things.

Comment: Either would be fine :)

Comment: but the solution is different depending on what you want

Comment: I really just need to be able to see if the value in quotes matches (exactly) another field in another table.

Comment: @Padawan - I copied your comment about what you REALLY need to your question (where it belongs). I also deleted the sqlplus tag - this has nothing to do with SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()` . . .

```
select regexp_substr(field, '"[^"]*"', 1, 1)
```

If you don't want the double quotes in the result, you can use `replace()` to remove them:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(field, '"[^"]*"', 1, 1), '"', '')
```

Comment: `trim()` instead of `replace` would be more efficient as it would only check at the ends of the string, not everywhere throughout the string. But simply doing `regexp_substr(field, '"([^"]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1)` would be even more efficient in a solution using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see that part of your field matches another string in another field in another table, you should use the LIKE operator. Assuming you must ensure the string appears within quotes in the "first" field, you could use something like:

```
... where table1.field1 LIKE '%"' || table2.field2 || '"%'
```

For example:

```
with table1 (id, txt) as (
     select 1, 'SYS.Data("THE DATA I WANT")' from dual union all
     select 3, 'SYS.Data("THE DATA I HAVE")' from dual
     ),
     table2 (comp_string) as (select 'THE DATA I WANT' from dual)
select id, txt
from table1 join table2
on txt like '%"' || comp_string || '"%'
;

        ID TXT
---------- ---------------------------
         1 SYS.Data("THE DATA I WANT")

1 row selected.
```

If you need to perform a comparison ignoring case (upper or lower), you can wrap both sides of the `like` operator within `upper()`.

**Note**: Since Oracle doesn't treat NULL character values according to the SQL standard, you will find that this solution returns rows when `table1.field1` contains two double-quotes in immediate succession (with nothing between them) when the column `field2` in `table2` contains NULL. As usual, if this is not the desired behavior, it can be avoided by adding the condition `...where table2.field2 is not NULL`.